# Is there any apocryphal gospel where someone else is crucified?

Tags: crucifixion, islam, apocrypha

In Islam Jesus is not crucified but instead of Him someone else is crucified, and Jesus went directly to heaven.

Moslims told me that Mohammed received his information about Jesus from the angel Gabriel. But in Mohammeds' days he probably knew or heared about gospels telling another story of Jesus like He wasn't crucified. But is there a gospel known where that is the case?

Comment: of interest: letusreason.org/Islam7.htm  Also, please note that there are groups of people who believe Islam is a derivative of Gnostic Christianity.  When looking at it from a macro scale, it make sense.  However either group would not admit it.

Answer (score 2):

There are various Gnostic Knowledge Gospels where Jesus wasn't crucified - I won't list them all but here are the most popular.

**Gnostic Apocalypse of Peter**

> He whom you saw on the tree, glad and laughing, this is the living
>   Jesus. But this one into whose hands and feet they drive the nails is
>   his fleshly part, which is the substitute being put to shame, the one
>   who came into being in his likeness. But look at him and me.

**The Second Treatise of The Great Seth, 56.6-19 in NHL 332**

> It was another...who drank the gall and the vinegar
>   (on the cross); it was not I... it was another Simon, who bore the
>   cross on his shoulder. It was another upon whom they placed the crown
>   of thorns. But I was rejoicing in the height (the hills) over... their
>   error. And I was laughing at their ignorance.

Comment: Listing documents without also detailing their relationship to Christianity does a disservice to this asker and others that may find this question.

Comment: "Is there any apocryphal gospel where someone else is crucified?" I believe is the question.  I'd have to write a book in order to detail the relationship between these two books and Christianity and I'm not sure that it helps answer the question.  I agree to disagree.

Comment: Those are some pretty strange depictions of Christ: laughing at someone else being crucified. This makes a little more sense out of how Muslims came to think that; it also appears to limit more the things that an angel would have needed to 'reveal' when its possible someone could gleam the same thing by picking up the right papyrus..

Comment: @shiningcartoonist if you were not familiar with the story of Jesus walking on water, you may find that strange too.  It is all relative